# Question about Multilinear forms and cartesian products

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

This is a pretty elementary question, but when talking about Multilinear forms, we can have F:VxVxV...V -> U, where it maps from the cartesian product consisting of n copies of V onto U. My question is simply; does this mean that we're taking n vectors from V, and mapping them onto U? For example, F:VxVxV -> R where F(u, v, w) = k where u,v,w are vectors of V and k is a real number.

Is this a correct interpretation of multilinear forms?

Also, follow-up question if it is; Is the cartesian product of two or more vector spaces, let's say VxV, a vector space itself?

Comment: A point regarding your second question: yes $V \times V$ is a vector space, but a multilinear map $F:V \times V \to U$ is not a **linear** map on $V \times V$.  $F$ does, however, induce a linear map on the tensor product $V \otimes V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean that, but multilinear forms should also be linear in each argument. That is, if $F:V\times V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for example, then we need that $$F(\alpha u_1+\beta u_2, v,w)=\alpha F(u_1,v,w)+\beta F(u_2, v,w),$$ and similarly for the other variables.

To your second question, yes, in the natural way, and you can check it directly via the definition of vector space.